# How shall I implement event handling in fabric js in angular. Normally it doesn't work

Tags: angular, angular8, fabricjs

I am new to using fabricjs in Angular. I want to use event handling feature provided in fabric.js using 'on' method. But somehow it's not working. Can anybody help?
I am using below code :

```
  canvas: fabric.Canvas;
  rect: fabric.Rect;
  constructor(private zone: NgZone) { }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
      this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
        backgroundColor: 'lightgrey', width: 400, height: 400
      });

      this.rect = new fabric.Rect({
        width: 100, height: 100, angle: 45, left: 100, top: 100, fill: 'white',
        borderColor: 'orange', selectable: true,
      })

      this.canvas.add(this.rect)
      const obj = this.rect.on('mouse:down', (e) => {
          console.log('mouse:down', e);
      })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to attach the event handler to the object?

You can do:

```
  this.canvas.on('selection:created', (e) => {
      console.log(e);
  });
```

And `e` will be the object you selected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
@HostListener("mousedown", ["$event"])
OnMouseDown(evt: MouseEvent) {
    console.log("MOUSE DOWN ", evt.button)
    // 0 for left, 1 for middle, 2 for right 
    if (evt.button === 0) {
        //custom code on left click. 
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.